# a-frame a-video not working black or withe results

Tags: aframe, virtualization, virtual-reality, 360-virtual-reality, 360-panorama

- A-Frame Version: 1.0.4
- Platform / Device: chrome safari firefox /mac os sierra
- Reproducible Code Snippet or URL:

```
...
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/oscarmarinmiro/aframe-video-controls/master/dist/aframe-video-controls.min.js"></script>
  </head>  
<a-video position="0 2.2 -0.5" rotation="0 0 0" width="3" height="2" depth="0" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/7mi6b0hk0j4qaj0/3079389037345071501.MOV"></a-video>
```

not working white results

```
...
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/oscarmarinmiro/aframe-video-controls/master/dist/aframe-video-controls.min.js"></script>
  </head>  
<a-assets><video id="penguin-sledding" autoplay src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/7mi6b0hk0j4qaj0/3079389037345071501.MOV"></video></a-assets>
<a-video position="0 2.2 -0.5" rotation="0 0 0" width="3" height="2" depth="0" src="#penguin-sledding"></a-video>
```

not working black results

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem is scr=... dropbox

if i put a local file no problem at all

i saw there is like access-control-allow-origin to put in the code, but i have not really understand where and how